# Remove the "mean" row from table1 function in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to remove the "Mean[SD]" rows for numeric variables when using the table1 function? I just want to have frequency and % for categorical variables and Median[Range] for numeric variables. An example is below.

```
library(table1)

number<-c(1:10)
pet<-c("cat","cat","dog","dog","dog","cat","dog","dog","cat","dog")

df<-tibble(number,pet)

table1(~number|pet,data=df)
```

Comment: can you share your code and data

Comment: sure, see edits

Answer (score 0):

The `gtsummary` package does this by default:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

number<-c(1:10)
pet<-c("cat","cat","dog","dog","dog","cat","dog","dog","cat","dog")

df<-tibble(number,pet)

tbl_summary(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
table1(~number|pet,data=df, render.continuous=c(.="Median [Min, Max]"))
```